# jquery-jqgrid:How to post value in toolbar search?

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid, toolbar

This my jqGrid search toolbar script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqGrid/plugins/ui.multiselect.css" />
    <script src="jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqGrid/src/jquery.fmatter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqGrid/src/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'dounfinish.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:['id','Date', 'Line'],
        colModel :[ 
                   {name:'def_id', index:'def_id', hidden:true, width:55}, 
                   {name:'Problem_date', index:'Problem_date', width:90, editable:true}, 
                   {name:'Line', index:'Line', width:80, align:'right',                   editable:true,search:true,stype:'text',searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']}}],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        sortname: 'Problem_date',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: 'themes/basic/images',
        caption: 'OQC DEFECT DATA'
        });

jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:false,del:false,search:false});
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, groupOp:'AND'});
```

And in console:

```
_search:true
nd:1306513344121
rows:10
page:1
sidx:Problem_date
sord:desc
filters:{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Line","op":"cn","data":"7"}]}
```

how should I do to post the "data" value? so, I can search data use toolbar search.

---

[image: grid]

Comment: You should **never** include the same javascript code more as one time: `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`, `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`, `jquery.fmatter.js`, `jqModal.js`. Moreover you should addend and not full rewrite your question. Now you replaced one question with another one and my previous answer is absolutely unclear for other reader. You original problem that you has `"op":"bw"` instead of `"op":"cn"`. The problem is solved? What do you mean with `post the "data" value`? The "07" was the data which you typed in the searching toolbar. The data was posted. Were are the problem?

Comment: @Oleg:How should I do, I've already change?

Comment: @Oleg: I guest that my problem come to `"op"`.but after I change it my toolbar search still no function.I have removed the javascript code as you said but, still not work.

Comment: @nunu: What you mean under "the code still not work"? Do the data about the filter send to the server? It "yes", then your server code should read the `filters` parameter decode JSON string, analyze it and use the information in the SQL statement which get the data from the database. The `filters` parameter should be used to construct the `WHERE` part of the corresponding `SELECT` statement. All this is already another problem. You can download the demo files from the http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 and examine the `search_adv.php` file.

Comment: @Oleg: may be I need to learn it first.

Comment: @nunu: If you use `datatype: 'json'` without `loadonce:true`, **the server** is responsible for sorting, paging and filtering of the data. The jqGrid just send the corresponding information in the parameters (rows, page, sidx, sord, _search:true, filters). If you don't can or don't want to do all this on the server side you can just use `loadonce:true` and the client part (jqGrid yourself) will change `datatype` to 'local' after the first load and will do all what you need itself. It work very good if the size of you data small (about 100 rows). You can try this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use `defaultSearch:'cn'` option of the [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching) method:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, defaultSearch:'cn'});
```

(I removed additionally the options with the default values).

If you use local grid data or the option `loadonce:true` another jqGrid parameter [ignoreCase:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) could be also interesting for you.

**UPDATED**: If you want to use different searching operations for the different columns you should use correct `colModel` options: `searchoptions` instead of `searchoption` ('s' character at the end).

**UPDATED 2**: How you can verify [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/nunu.htm) if you type `bla` in the searching toolbar in the 'Line' column the request with the data

```
_search=true&nd=1306489580463&rows=10&page=1&sidx=Problem_date&sord=desc&filters=%7B%22groupOp%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22Line%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22cn%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22bla%22%7D%5D%7D
```

will be send to the server which will be decoded as

```
_search=true&nd=1306489580463&rows=10&page=1&sidx=Problem_date&sord=desc&filters={"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Line","op":"cn","data":"bla"}]}
```

So the operation which will be used is "cn".

**UPDATED 3**: If you use `datatype: 'json'` without `loadonce:true`, **the server is responsible for sorting, paging and filtering of the data**. The jqGrid just send the corresponding information in the parameters (`rows`, `page`, `sidx`, `sord`, `_search:true`, `filters`). If you don't can or don't want to do all this on the server side you can just use `loadonce:true` and the client part (jqGrid yourself) will change `datatype` to 'local' *after the first load* and will do all what you need itself. It work very good if the size of you data small (about 100 rows). You can try this way.

Comment: whats the different using 's' character and not?

Comment: @Oleg: it makes my grid can't filter data.

Comment: @nunu: I don't understand your question. There are an option `searchoptions` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options)) which will be read and interpret by jqGrid. There are no option `searchoption` which is unknown and will be ignored.

Comment: @nunu: You don't posted your code. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbar.htm) and compare with your code. You should post full your code. It can has syntax errors like ',]' at the end of the `colModel` definition.

Comment: @Oleg: sorry, I'm new for jqgrid. how to post this value? any documentations?

Comment: @nunu: Want do you mean? Which value? You can edit the text of your question any time and add your full code which define jqGrid.

Comment: @Oleg: I have post whole jqgrid.

Comment: @nunu: Everything work correct in the grid now the "cn" operation will be send (see "UPDATED 2" part of my answer). You should just repeat your experiments. For your code I just removed deprecated option `imgpath` and replaced `jQuery('#pager')` to '#pager' and added the `gridview:true` option.

Comment: thanks oleg, after I'm using `loadonce:true` I can do toolbar search.could you update your answer?